# Bind StackPanel.Visibility to the Visibility property of its children

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml

I'm relatively new to DataBinding and just reading into it.
What I want to do is the following:

I have a StackPanel with a number of child controls:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Width="100">1</TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Width="100">2</TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="textbox3" Width="100">3</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

The `visibility` property of the textboxes can be changed by code.
Now, if all `TextBoxe`s are set to `Visibility=Collapsed`, i also want `StackPanel.Visibility` set to `Collapsed`, but if one or more `TextBoxe`s are shown `(Visibility=Visible)`, `StackPanel.Visibility` should also be set to `Visible`.

Can this be achieved with a simple DataBinding or do I have to implement this functionality in C# code?

Answer (score 7):

I can not think of a way to do this directly through databinding.

Personally I would have a view model behind the view, and set the views DataContext to the view model.

In the view model I would then have a property telling the view if all the textboxes are collapsed. That property would be set by code. Then bind the stackpanel visibility to that property.

(The property must either be a dependancy property, or the view model must implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the view to automatically update)

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered setting the visibility of the TextBoxes to `Hidden`? This will "hide" the space that is assigned for the TextBoxes. Assuming their are no other controls in the StackPanel, then it will not be visible.

Of course, this solution may make some naive assumptions about your implementation.

If you need the more complex scenario, I would attempt the following:
Note: This is psuedocode - may not compile..

1) Use a MultiBinding

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.Visibility Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}>
    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
      <Binding ElementName="textBox1" Path="Visibility" />
      <Binding ElementName="textBox2" Path="Visibility" />
      <Binding ElementName="textBox3" Path="Visibility" />
    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
  </StackPanel.Visibility>
</StackPanel>
```

2) Declare the Converter

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

3) Define the Converter

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    Visibility text1Vis = (Visibility)values[0];
    Visibility text2Vis = (Visibility)values[1];
    Visibility text3Vis = (Visibility)values[2];

    if (text1Vis == text2Vis == text3Vis == Visibility.Collapsed)
      return Visibility.Collapsed;

    return Visibility.Visible;
  }
}
```

Comment: Small error: Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter} should go on MultiBinding.Bindings instead of Visibility

Comment: Syntax errors in XAML.  Converter goes on MultiBinding element.  Change <MultiBinding.Bindings> to <MultiBinding>.  (You can have property element syntax without a parent element above).  Need to compile code before posting it.

Comment: @SeanSexton, I noted in my answer that I was giving psuedocode. I actually posted 9 minutes after the original question was asked so I didn't get chance to run up a full project and test the code. The beauty of this site is that you can jump in an edit my response though. :-)