# How to hide control when other two controls are already hidden?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have WPF Grid with one row and three columns:

Label1 | control1 | control2

I want to set `Label1` visibility to hidden when both controls are hidden:

Any easy way to do this in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Multibinding and a MultiConverter on Label1.Visibility to do this job

or you use Style Trigger for your Label1 and set the initial visibility to hidden and use 2 triggers to set the visibility to visible if one of the controls are visible

EDIT

```
    <Label x:Name=Label1>
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ctl1, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ctl2, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569144/bind-stackpanel-visibility-to-the-visibility-property-of-its-children